# Copy rich text format string as formatted text

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook, copy, rtf

I have a rtf string that i coppied to my clipboard ( from C#/Javascript code ).
User should be able to copy that text into Outlook. Only it should be the nice looking and user friendly formatted text and not the actual rtf string.

How do i 'convert' this string into nice formatted text ?
( In this case outlook is a rich text editor, but it takes the string as plain text )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to use the right parameters when you add the `rtf` data to the clipboard.

Here is C# code that was tested to wark for copying formatted text from a `RichtTextBox` into WordPad:

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, (Object)richTextBox1.Rtf);
```

If your rtf text is already in the clipboard in the wrong, plain-text format, simply retrieve it and put it back correctly:

```
string temp = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, (Object)temp);
```

Comment: Allright, would you happen to know a way to achieve this in javascript ?

Comment: At first glance JavaScript doen't have many data formats. Rtf doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not fetching styles I guess try with absolute URL instead of relative URL

Comment: I don't think we're on the same line. I have a page with a button, when the user clicks this button some text ( rich text format ) is coppied to the user's clipboard. Now this needs to be coppied to a rich text editor ( like outlook ). But not as plain text ( plain text including all the rtf format elements )